# Ninject inject across assemblies

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ninject

I have MVC project, which handle frontend and Infrastructure project, which handles backend operation, i.e.

- **Cool.UI**
- **Cool.Infrastructure**

And UI is dependent on infrastructure. Now Im trying to add logging, interfaces and implementation are both in **Cool.Infrastructure**. I have NinjectModule in **Cool.UI**, which does the following:

```
    public class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {


        public override void Load()
        {
            //logging interfaces
            this.Kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<ApplicationLogger>();
        }
     }
```

I inject via properties, i.e.:

```
[Inject]
public ILogger Log { get; set; }
```

When i do it on the **Cool.UI**, I can use the Logger, when I do it in the backend I get null in Log object. I have tried adding Bindings module to **Cool.Infrastructure**, that didnt work. Since Im using Ninject.WebCommons, I tried to load library separately

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Bindings)));
}
```

Where Bindings is an empty NinjectModule in **Cool.Infrastructure**. No success any idea why?

Comment: If you just have these projects as references in the Cool.UI project, you can just wire it all up in there, makes it a bit simpler. I would also steer away from using attributes as that couple your classes to Ninject.

Comment: There are just 2 projects UI and infrastructure and Infrastructure is references in UI

Comment: Yeah, so in your UI project, under the App_Start register all the services in there. What do you mean by "backend"?

Comment: I have standard NinjectWebCommon in AppStart can you, pls, provide some code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a new MVC5 project. I added the NuGet Package `Ninject.MVC5`. I added the `Infrastructure` project as a reference in the `UI` project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>();
}
```

Here I have `Bind`ed the interface to concrete.

To use property injection I do this:

```
private ILogger Logger
{
    get
    {
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();
    }
}
```

The `DependencyResolver` is the Service Locator, it is set by Ninject when the application gets started. From here you can resolve all dependencies that you have created

Comment: Personally I never use the `[Inject]` attributes. Are you saying that my `DependencyResolver` didn't work? or your method?